# Between two Unix dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks to previous question...

I have a more simplified OR statement.

Question is instead of a IN how could I change this to a between?

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) IN (''23-DEC-2020'', ''29-DEC-2020'')
```

So I want to say between the 23-DEC-2020 and 29-DEC-2020 including both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change_date` seems to be in Unix timestamp format -- the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  I would recommend doing the comparison by converting constant values to the same format:

```
where ph.change_date >= (date '2020-12-23' - date '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60 and
      ph.change_date < (date '2020-12-30' - date '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Note that this is index (and partition) friendly.  And, the second comparison is `<` on the *next* day to get the entire day.

If you need to deal with the column as "real" dates, you can add a computed column

```
alter table t add column change_date_date date generated always as
     (cast(date '1970-01-01' as timestamp) + change_date * interval '1' second);
```

You can then reference `change_date_date` and even define a an index on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an index on the `change_date` column then perform the conversion on the literal values and convert them to epoch times (rather than converting the column's epoch time to a date, which would not allow you to use a normal index on the column):

```sql
ph.change_date BETWEEN ( DATE '2020-12-23' - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 86400
               AND     ( DATE '2020-12-29' - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 86400 + 86399
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the between keyword.

For example:

```
to_date('2021.01.06', 'yyyy.mm.dd') between to_date('2021.01.01', 'yyyy.mm.dd') and to_date('2021.01.31', 'yyyy.mm.dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can try like this

```
where <expression> 
between TO_DATE('23-DEC-2020','DD-MON-YYYY') and 
TO_DATE('29-DEC-2020','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the epoch time(`ph.change_date`) to date and then compare as follows:

```
Date'1970-01-01' + FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60) -- considering that change_date is epoch time
    between date'2020-12-23' and date'2020-12-23'
```